# How to create an expandable 'drawer' by double-clicking on a row in ag-grid?

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I would like to use ag-grid to display an expandable 'drawer' which appears just beneath a row and to display additional data about the row's record.

I've read tons of docs but I can't seem to find a simple way to do this. Has anyone else achieved this before?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're talking about this: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-master-detail/

Or possibly this: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping/.

Both are enterprise features, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks thirtydot - I'll check those out.